# IndexError at /new-watch-hour-graph/

Tags: python-3.x

```
def getNewWatchedCountGraph(requests):
    data = Video.getNewWatchedCountGraph(requests)
    data = json.loads(data)
    # print(data)
    x = []
    m = []
    bg = {}
    res = {}
    monthnumbers = []

    currentMonth = datetime.datetime.now().month
    for item in data:
        seconds = int(item['count'])
        x.append(seconds)
        mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(item['_id'], "%Y-%m")
        monthnumbers.append(mydate.month)
        m.append(mydate.strftime("%B"))

    startMonths = monthnumbers[0] #line 116
    endMonths = currentMonth+1

    data = []
    mon = []

    for months in range(startMonths,endMonths):
        if months not in monthnumbers:
            mon.append(calendar.month_name[months])
            data.append(0)
        else:
            mon.append(calendar.month_name[months])
            monthIndex = monthnumbers.index(months)
            data.append(x[monthIndex])


    res['series_name'] = "Views"
    res['series'] = list(data)
    res['xdata'] = list(mon)

    restrn_response = dumps(res)
    return HttpResponse(restrn_response)
```

I have made this function to show the graph of total number of views.
It is working fine in my local server. But showing List index out of range in main server at line no 116. Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where's line 116?

Comment: @ForceBru I have updated.. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `monthnumbers` is empty. Given that it’s being filled while iterating over `data`, I think the loop doesn’t even start because `data` is empty.

Comment: @Upasana, supply the data?

Comment: give some suggetion

Comment: @Upasana, see what `Video.getNewWatchedCountGraph` returns. Is it the empty list? If so, you’re probably supplying some incorrect input to it, or just don’t have any `Video`s to retrieve.